# Laravel update join table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

so I have 2 tables (projects and project_types) with OneToMany relationship.

```
public function project_types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProjectType', 'project_type_id');
}

public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project', 'project_type_id');
}
```

My ProjectController:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('get')){

        $types = ProjectType::all()
            ->pluck('name');

        // dd($types);
        return view('projects.form', compact('types'), ['project' => Project::find($id)]);
    }

    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'project_code' => 'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails())
        return response()->json([
            'fail' => true,
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ]);

    $project = Project::find($id);
    $project->name = $request->name;
    $project->description = $request->description;
    $project->project_code = $request->project_code;
    $project->project_type_id = $request->project_type_id;
    $project->start_p = $request->start_p;
    $project->start_r = $request->start_r;
    $project->end_p = $request->end_p;
    $project->end_r = $request->end_r;
    $project->days_p = $request->days_p;
    $project->days_r = $request->days_r;
    $project->date_requested = $request->date_requested;

    $project->save();

    return response()->json([
        'fail' => false,
        'redirect_url' => url('projects')
    ]);
}
```

My form:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        {!! Form::label("project_types", trans('project.Type'),["class"=>"col-form-label col-md-3 col-lg-2"]) !!}
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::select("project->project_type_id", $types, null, ["class"=>"form-control".($errors->has('project->project_type_id')?" is-invalid":""),'placeholder'=>'Project Type']) !!}
            <span id="error-name" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my form view I have a dropdown list with all project types names (so I guess my relationship is good), but when I try to update the project information, the form sends NULL for the project_type_id. I don't get any errors in the console.

Can anyone help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the request from the browser to the server and  the relevant HTML that is produced by your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class, 'project_type_id', 'id');
}

public function project_types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectType::class, 'project_type_id', 'id');
}
```

And in your controller change this:

```
if ($request->isMethod('get')){

        $types = ProjectType::all()
            ->pluck('name');

        // dd($types);
        return view('projects.form', compact('types'), ['project' => Project::find($id)]);
    }
```

To this:

```
if ($request->isMethod('get')){

        $types = ProjectType::all()
            ->pluck('name');
        $project = Project::find($id);
        // dd($types);
        return view('projects.form', compact('types', 'project'));
    }
```

And according to your blade template, i guess that you have some errors in `Form::select()`

[Laravel docs Forms & HTML](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

`Form::select('select_name', $types->toArray());`

Answer (score 0):

OK found my error. I was selecting the project type name, I needed the id as well.

```
 $types = ProjectType::all()
            ->pluck('name', 'id');

        return view('projects.form', compact('types', 'project'));
```

and in the form:

```
 {!! Form::label("project_types", trans('project.Type'),["class"=>"col-form-label col-md-3 col-lg-2"]) !!}
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::select("project_type_id", $types, null, ["class"=>"form-control".($errors->has('project_type_id')?" is-invalid":""),'placeholder'=>'Project Type']) !!}
            <span id="error-name" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
        </div>
```